# Using getString outside an Activity

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to access my Resource outside an activity. But, it's not accessing it. It's giving **NullPointerException** my code is below

```
public class OrderDataRetrieval {

    Context context;

    public OrderDataRetrieval(Context myContext){
        context = myContext;
    }

    public void getData(String getToken, final Uri uri1, final Uri uri2, final Uri uri3){

        String order_URL = "http://xxxxxxxx?token=" + getToken + "&contain=Issue,OrderItem";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                order_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("REPLY", response.toString());
                        handleResponse(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    public void handleResponse(JSONObject response){



        try {
            JSONObject respOrd = response.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONObject dataOrd = respOrd.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray ordersArr = dataOrd.getJSONArray("orders");
            //JSONArray issuesArray = ordersArr.getJSONArray(0);
            //JSONArray itemArray = ordersArr.getJSONArray(1);
            //String getIt = context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER);
            Log.d("TEST", uri1.toString());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/orders");
            //Log.d("TAGURL", uri2.toString());
            Uri itemUri = Uri.parse("content://" + context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/oitems");
            Uri issuesUri = Uri.parse("content://" + context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/oissues");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The area I'm using **Uri** is where I get the error. If you can help with a fix, I'll be glad. Thanks

Comment: Where exactly does NPE happen? Add logcat dump to your post.

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/orders");

Comment: So `uri1` is null, you pass it as a parameter, how is this related to resources?

Comment: Sorry, not uri1, the uri itself

Comment: When and where you instatiate the `OrderDataRetrieval` object? I think that the `context` instance is `null` in that moment.

Comment: I'm calling it in a fragment class, just trying to limit codes in every class

Comment: Are you instantiating it after `onAttach` or `onActivityCreated` is called? And passing the `Activity` instance as parameter?

Comment: I call it onViewCreated

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In `onViewCreated` the `getActivity()` returns an valid instance. But there's no problem using the `Resources` outside `Activity`. Can you check if `context` is `null` or the return of `context.getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER)` is `null`?

Comment: It's null, I checked it. And that's why it throws NPE

Comment: You have to check if when you instastiate OrderDataRetrieval, the Context parameter is not null. You can always check if it is null. If it is, use new OrderDataRetrieval(getActivity)

Comment: @joao2fast4u yeah it worked using (getActivity). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make context final.  There no object link back to the OrderDataRetrieval object. Its getting deleted before to response returns

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if when you instastiate `OrderDataRetrieval`, on your `Fragment`, the `Context` parameter is not null. You can always check if it is null. 
If it is, use:

`new OrderDataRetrieval(getActivity)`.

Like this, you are passing your fragment's `Activity` `Context` object.